# Why does Firebase REST API responses have different arrays for different data types?

Tags: firebase, google-api

In Google Firebase, there are values like: `StringValue, IntValue, DoubleValue` etc. Why is that? Why separate the values? 
I was just wondering why Google created an array with dataTypes like:

```
stringColumn: [
  "Val1", "Val2"
]
```

```
doubleColumn: [
  1.2, 4.4
]
```

```
intColumn: [
  1, 50
]
```

Why is there an different array key for doubles (`doubleColumn`) and strings (`stringColumn`)? They can use JSON's build-in data types right and just have one key `columns`? What are the benefits of separating the datatypes that way? See image for a example response.

[Example response of Google where this is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QluHG.png)

Thanks, if you need more explanation please let me know